# Install ros2 humble desktop in my Ubuntu it shows E : unable to locate package

Tags: apt

I am trying to install ros2 humble desktop in my Ubuntu it shows:

```
E : Unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop
```

Issues I faced during dual boot and installing ros2
[image]